# How to delete specific item from array in swift?

Tags: arrays, swift, xcode

I am using an array that is filled with structs:

```
struct CartModel: Codable {
    var product_id: Int
    var line_subtotal: Float
    var line_total: Float
    var line_tax: Float
    var line_subtotal_tax: Float
    var key: String
    var quantity: Int
}

    static var fullCart = [CartModel]()
```

Now I am trying to delete one of those from the array.
I tried to use `fullCart.index(of:)`, but it is giving me the following error:

> Argument labels '(of:, _:)' do not match any available overloads

I was hoping to use `fullCart.remove(at:)`, but because of not being able to find the right index I am not sure how to remove the right item.

Comment: You need to make your CartModel conform to Equatable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You also can find index by [`index(where:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/1688966-index) and then delete item from array:

```
if let index = fullCart.index(where: { $0.product_id == otherCartModel.product_id }) {
    fullCart.remove(at: index)
}
```

Or conform to [`Equatable`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/equatable) protocol and use `index(of:)`:

```
struct CartModel: Codable, Equatable {
    ...

    static func == (lhs: Self, rhs: Self) -> Bool {
        return lhs.product_id == rhs.product_id
    }
}

if let index = fullCart.index(of: otherCartModel) {
    fullCart.remove(at: index)
}
```